# How To Search Item In user control Panel?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, user-controls

When I try to search data in my user control from my database it does search or filter the data that I typed in the search textbox. Here's the code that I'm using to try and search or filter

```
SqlConnection cn;
SqlCommand cm;
SqlDataReader dr;

 private Label name;
    
 private Label amount;

 private Label descrip;
    
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)");
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
}

private void GetData()
{

    cn.Open();
      cm = new SqlCommand("Select * from Bills where (billname) like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'", cn);
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                long len = dr.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, 0);
                byte[] array = new byte[System.Convert.ToInt32(len) + 1];
                dr.GetBytes(0, 0, array, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(len));

                name = new Label();
                        name.Text = dr["billname"].ToString();

                descrip = new Label();
                descrip.Text = dr["billdescrip"].ToString();

                amount = new Label();
                amount.Text = dr["billamount"].ToString();
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
}

private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
}
```

When I type something into the txtSearch.text box, the results come back empty and doesn't display the what im trying to search for in the txtSearch.text box.

Comment: When form1 loads does it display results?

Comment: It shows the data from the database but when I do a search the panel disappears. I'm usercontrol,controls.clear() which is suppose to filter the data and bring back what I typed in the search bar but its not doing that

Comment: @ForeverUnknownNicholas what do you mean by `I'm usercontrol,controls.clear() which is suppose to filter the data`? That sentence doesn't make any sense, `Controls.Clear()` will remove the controls from the panel. Also, why are you re-creating the Label for `name`, `descrip` and `amount` when you can just change the `.Text` instead? Also, it would be better if instead of performing the query every time a `TextChanged` event fires, you instead get all the data once at the beginning and then filter the data inside the `TextChanged` event to find the record matching and then update the UI.

Comment: BTW: [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) alert.

Comment: I've watched this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WenNmob2oCo. In the link they flowlayoutpanel.control.clear(). In my project, I 'm a flowlayout panel but I also added a user control on the flow layout panel s=and trying to do a search on the user control

Answer (score 0):

```
"Select * from Bills where (billname) like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'"
```

It seems to me that you have a database table `Bills`, with a column `BillName`. The operator types some text in TextBox `txtSearch`, and you want to fetch all Bills that have a BillName that starts with the text in the TextBox.

I see several problems here

### SQL Injection

SQL injection is a code injection technique that might destroy your database.
SQL injection is one of the most common web hacking techniques.
SQL injection is the placement of malicious code in SQL statements

Look what your Sql text would be if the operator types the following text:
"John%; DROP TABLE Bills;--"

```
Select * from Bills where (billname) like %John%; DROP TABLE Bills; --%
```

You would lose all Bills!

[More information about SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Solution: **Never, ever add input data into your sql string!** Always add it as a parameter!

### Start using using statements

The database connection is a scarce resource: you should not keep it alive longer than needed. Also, if you SQL query encounters an exception, the connection and the datareader are not closed.

> Make it a habit, that whenever an object implements IDisposable you should use it using a using statement.

This way, you can be assured that whatever happens, at the end of the using statement everything is properly flushed, written, closed and disposed.

SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader should be private members of GetData. This way you can be certain that no one can tamper with your connection; you hide how you fetch the data from the database (SQL and SqLCommand, or Entity Framework and LINQ?), thus making future changes easier. Readers of your code won't have to check where these variables are used, and that no one is misusing it, thus making your code easier to understand. And of course this will make it possible to reuse GetData for other purposes.

Which brings me to the third improvement:

### Separate data from how it is displayed

In modern programming you see more and more a separation between the date (= model) and the way that the data is displayed (= view).

- Separation makes it better to reuse the code, for instance: if you want to use your model in a console program, or in a WPF program, or even a different Form, you can reuse the model classes.
- Separation hides how and where you fetch your data: is it a database? is it a CSV file, or XML? are you using Entity Framework
- This hiding allows future changing without having to change all your Forms
- This hiding also makes your Forms smaller and easier to understand
- While developing the form, you can mock the actual data: just create a dummy class that provides you with sample data, without having to bother about the database
- You can unit test the model, without needing a form
- It is hardly any extra work.

So you'll have Model classes: your data, and how it is saved, fetched again; and View classes: your Forms. You'll need an adapter class to adapt the model to the view: the ViewModel. Together these three abbreviate to MVVM. Consider to do some background reading about MVVM.

### Implementing the three advices

We create a class that makes it possible to save Bills (and other items: Customers? Orders? Products? etc) and later you can retrieve them again, even after you restarted the program. Something like a warehouse, a repository, where you store items and fetch them again.

```
interface IOrderRepository
{
    int AddBill(Bill bill);         // return Id of the Bill
    Bill FindBill(int Id);          // null if not found

    // your GetData:
    IEnumerable<Bill> FetchBillsWithNameLike(string name);

    ... // other methods, about Customers, Orders, etc
}
```

Implementation:

```
class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    private string ConnectionString {get;} = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)";

    private IDbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
    }
```

The implementation of FetchBillsWithNameLike:

```
    public IEnumerable<Bill> FetchBillsWithNameLike(string name)
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = this.CreateConnection())
        {
            const string sqlText = "Select Id, BillName, CustomerId, ..."
               + " from Bills where (billname) like %@Name%";

            using (IDbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                // fill the command and the parameter:
                dbCommand.CommandText = sqlText;
                dbCommand.AddParameterWithValue("@Name", name);

                // execute the command and enumerate the result
                dbConnection.Open();
                using (IDatareader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dbReader.Read())
                    {
                        // There is a Bill to read
                        Bill bill = new Bill
                        {
                            Id = dbReader.ReadInt32(0),
                            Name = dbReader.ReadString(1),
                            CustomerId = dbReader.ReadInt32(2),
                            ...
                         };
                         yield return bill;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // implement rest of interface
}
```

Several improvements:

- Connection string is a property. If you decide to use a different connection string for all your 100 methods: only one place to change.
- You hide where you get the connection string: here it is a constant, but if you decide in future versions to read it from the config file: no one has to know, except this method
- You hide that you are using a SqlConnection, you return the interface. If in future versions you decide to create a different form of IDbConnection, for instance for a different kind of database, like SQLite, no one has to know that you create a  SqlLiteConnection object instead of a SqlConnection.
- Similarly: hide SqlCommand, use the interface IDbCommand.
- The database connection is not opened before it is needed. This makes it possible that others can use the database as long as you will not use it.
- `using` statements all over the place: if any exception happens, all objects are properly closed and disposed.
- I don't create the DbCommand myself, I ask the DbConnection to create it for me, so I don't have to bother which type of commands the actual DbConnection uses: Is it SqlCommand? SQLiteCommand?
- I specify which columns from the table if want. If in future some columns are added, and I don't need them, I won't fetch more data than I want. Similarly: if columns are reordered, it will still work.

The most important change: Use SQL parameter to prevent malicious SQL Injection.

- Parameters in SQL text are often recognized by prefix `@`
- Parameters are added with the extension method [AddParameterWithValue](https://www.gridprotectionalliance.org/NightlyBuilds/GridSolutionsFramework/Help/html/M_GSF_Data_DataExtensions_AddParameterWithValue.htm)`. Some databases have this as a method in DbCommand (for example: SQLite)
- When reading the fetched data, I won't read more Bills than my caller wants. So if he calls me using the following code: not all Bills will be read:

  IOrderRepository repository = ...
  string name = this.ReadName();
  bool billsWithNameAvailable = repository.FetchBillsWithName(name).Any();

Here, my caller only wants to know if there are any Bills with the Name at all. The reader won't create any Bills at all.

Because the SQL text is `Select Id, ...` and I read `dbReader.GetInt32[0]` etc, my code will still work, even after inserting or reordering the columns of the table.

The nice thing is, that you will be able to unit test method FetchBillsWithName without having to use a Form: you can test what happens if there is no database at all, or if there is no Bills table, or an empty table, or the table doesn't contain a column BillName. Or what happens if the input text is empty. You can unit test all kinds of errors without need of a Form.

### The Form

```
class Form1 : ...
{
    private IOrderRepository Repository {get;} = new OrderRepository();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        string name = this.txtSearch.Txt;
        foreach(Bill fetchedBill in this.Repository.FetchBillsWithNameLike(name))
        {
            this.ProcessBill(fetchedBill);
        }
    }

    private void ProcessBill(Bill fetchedBill)
    {
        // do your stuff with the label;
    }
}
```

Because I separated the model from the view, the view is much simpler: much easier to see what really happens: you focus on the form, not on how and where you get the data.

During development, while you don't have a database yet, you can create a dummy repository and test your form:

```
class DummyRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    private Dictionary<int, Bill> Bills {get;} = ... // fill with some sample Bills

    // TODO: implement IOrderRepository, using this.Bills
}
```

If later you decide that you won't get your data from a database, but for instance from the internet, your form will hardly have to change. It can still use `IOrderRepository`

### Conclusion

- By separating the model from the view, both model and view are much easier to red and understand. Much easier to reuse, change, maintain and unit test. Both can be developed independantly
- Procedure are small and have only one task: this makes that we can reuse the procedures. Changes are only in one procedure
- By using interfaces, I hide how and where the data is fetched: SQL? CSV-file? Internet?
- By using using statements the program is more full proof: after exceptions everything is property closed and disposed
- By using SQL parameters I prevented malicious use of SQL injection.